# leaderboard and stage number not showing

Tags: roblox

```
local  Players = game:GetService("Players")

local CheckpointsFolder = game.Workspace.CheckPoints

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderStats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    
    local Stage =  Instance.new("IntValue")
    Stage.Name = "Stage"
    Stage.Parent = leaderstats
    
end)

for _, v  in pairs(CheckpointsFolder:GetChildren()) do
    
    if  v:isA("BasePart") then
        v.Touched:Connect(function(part)
            
            local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
            local stageValue = player.leaderstats.Stage
            
            if player and stageValue.Value < tonumber(v.Name) then
                
                stageValue.Value     = v.Name
                
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

This is the error im getting when i run the script :  ServerScriptService.CheckPointScript:23: attempt to index nil with 'leaderstats'
Can anyone fix it for me?

I was expecting a leaderboard and stage number to popup on the right hand upper side of my screen but that didnt happen. I also wanted to spawn at my checkpoint but im spawning in some random area

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be caused because the leaderStats folder is not being created properly for the player. This could be due to the fact that the PlayerAdded event fires after the loop through the checkpoints has already completed.

To fix this, you can move the loop inside the PlayerAdded event handler so that the checkpoints are processed only after the leaderstats folder has been created for the player. Additionally, to spawn the player at their last checkpoint, you can use the player.RespawnLocation property.

Here's the modified code:

local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

```
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
leaderstats.Name = "leaderStats"
leaderstats.Parent = player

local Stage =  Instance.new("IntValue")
Stage.Name = "Stage"
Stage.Parent = leaderstats

player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
    -- Set player respawn location to their last checkpoint
    if Stage.Value > 0 then
        player.RespawnLocation = game.Workspace.CheckPoints:FindFirstChild(tostring(Stage.Value))
    end
end)

-- Loop through checkpoints after leaderstats have been created for player
for _, v  in pairs(game.Workspace.CheckPoints:GetChildren()) do
    if  v:IsA("BasePart") then
        v.Touched:Connect(function(part)
            local touchedPlayer = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(part.Parent)
            if touchedPlayer == player then
                if Stage.Value < tonumber(v.Name) then
                    Stage.Value = tonumber(v.Name)
                    -- Set player respawn location to the checkpoint they just reached
                    player.RespawnLocation = v
                end
            end
        end)
    end
end
```

end)

Note: Make sure that the CheckpointsFolder variable is changed to game.Workspace.CheckPoints, as specified in the modified code above.